# Cannot query on IsPrivateDraft field of EmailMessage

Tags: apex, soql, apex-email-service, servicecloud, emailmessage

I have a field named IsPrivateDraft in EmailMessage, I want to use that field for updating the draft EmailMessage. I want to know the value of this field but cannot use it in query. On using the field in query I am given error "No such column 'isPrivateDraft' on entity 'EmailMessage'", even it is shown in the list of fields of EmailMessage in Developer Console.

Comment: Check the Field-Level Security for that field [Go to Setup > Open the field > Click on `Set Field-Level Security button` and check access]. Make sure you're using isPrivateDraft__c in your query. That's a custom field, so __c is important.

Comment: @N.B. I don't think `IsPrivateDraft` is custom field. i found this field in [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) but when i tried to get all fields through workbench it was not there.

Comment: It is not a custom field.